# Can't position div correctly

Tags: css, padding, margins

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZI9d.png

It the above image, I'm trying to get the text to nestle to the left of the menu bar and underneath the header. I've tried both margin and padding, but haven't had any luck. The buttons are all within a separate  tag from the text. Code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body
{
    background-image: url(Background.gif);
    repeat: no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.button
{
width: 220px;
padding:0px, 0px, 0px, 30px;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
}

div.textbox
{

    border: 0 px;
    margin-top: 300 px;
    margin-left: 300 px;
    background-color: white;
    opactiy: 0.5;
    width: 600 px;



}

span
{
    width: 600 px;
    padding: 90 px, 0 px, 0 px, 250px;
    font-family: "Letter Gothic Std Bold";
    font-size: 16 pt;
    color: #99CCFF;
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

<div class = "textbox"><span>
 text text text
</span></div>

<div class = "button">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img src="DarkLayout_03.gif" width="166" height="66" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img src="DarkLayout_06.gif" width="166" height="66" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="mailto:swy5105@psu.edu"><img src="DarkLayout_08.gif" width="166" height="66" /></a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href = "http://notafilmnoirheroine.tumblr.com"><img src="DarkLayout_11.gif" width="166" height="66" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href = "http://swy5105.tumblr.com"> <img src="DarkLayout_13.gif" width="166" height="66" /></a>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide the fiddle link of your code with images as well as a screenshot of how you want it to display.

Comment: What with all those br, you dont know that there margin exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the float left then clear after that.

Comment: Float left in place of padding/margin left? (Sorry if that seems like a dumb question).

Comment: what i mean is on each div you have.

Comment: No luck. I added the floats in the styling, though, so let me know if that was wrong.

Comment: Try to post it using fiddle.

Comment: Images aren't with this, but here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sodisarmingdarling/wg4xa/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pWurk/

u have to use `float: left`

i hope it will help u

Comment: Thank you! <3 I really appreciate it!